# control panel resets automatically

Tags: windows, default-settings, factory-defaults

I guarantee you haven't heard of this question before.
When I drag a window to the top of the screen Windows10 displays the "maximize" window animation in anticipation of automatically maximizing the windows for me.  I really hate this feature and turn it off out of habit.  Recently my computer has been unchecking the "prevent windows from.....screen" option.

[image]

A specific control panel setting unchecks itself several times a week.  I don't always notice it right away so I don't know when exactly it resets.

This happens on BOTH my personal home-built gaming PC -AND- my college laptop which is part of a domain.

Can I use a laser to permanently set the bit on the rotating magnetic media so that windows/FBI/aliens stop changing the bit back to windows default?  I will kill a squirrel every hour until this issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a value in the registry that is overriding my changes to the Control Panel

There are indeed registry keys associated with this particular setting.  I would try explicitly settings the registry keys in question and see if the behavior changes.

`WindowArrangementActive` is contained within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` while three additional keys (`JointResize`, `SnapFill`, and `SnapAssist`) are contained within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.

If the feature is enabled the value of these keys will be `0`and if they are disabled they have a value of `1`.  In my testing, the registry keys for (`JointResize`, `SnapFill`, and `SnapAssist`), might not exist initially if you have never disabled them through Settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In order for the keys to change you must explicitly disable the features within Settings, simply disabling "Snap windows" within Settings, does not seem to update the registry key.

Source: [How to Turn On or Off Snap Windows in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-turn-off-snap-windows-windows-10-a.html#option3)